# How do i fix HTTPSConnectionPool - Read Timed Out Error when connecting to database server

Tags: python-3.x, https, filemaker

I am trying to connect to a FileMaker Databse server via python script, and my code was working before but has suddenly stopped, and i didnt make any changes to the portion of code that no longer works. I am encountering the following error:

`Request error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='**.**.*.*', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)`

I have taken out the code that creates the server instance and connects/logs in, and then logs out without making any changes in the database, and i am still recieving the same error. However, i can connect to the filemaker server and database via the FileMaker applicaiton with no issues, and i can connect to the server using Telnet commands. I am on windows 10 and writing the code in PyCharm CE. I have reinstalled PyCharm, created a new virtual environment, and tried reinstalling the fmrest module, as well as using older versions. I have also increased the timeout time to give more time to login, which hasnt worked. I'm basically stumped on why i can no longer log in via the script, when it has been working perfectly in testing for the past couple weeks. My code is below.

```py
import fmrest
from fmrest.exceptions import FileMakerError
from fmrest.exceptions import RequestException
import sys
import requests

# connect to the FileMaker Server
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
fmrest.utils.TIMEOUT = 30
try:
    fms = fmrest.Server('https://**.**.*.*',
                        user = '***',
                        password = '******',
                        database = 'Hangtag Order Management',
                        layout = 'OrderAdmin',
                        verify_ssl = False)
except ValueError as err:
    print('Failed to connect to server. Please check server credentials and status and try again\n\n' + str(err))
    sys.exit()

print(fms)
print('Attempting to connect to FileMaker Server...')

try:
    fms.login()
    print('Login Successful\n')
except FileMakerError as err:
    print(err)
    sys.exit()
except RequestException as err:
    print('There was an error connecting to the server, the request timed out\n\n' + str(err))
    sys.exit()

fms.logout()
```

This should successfully login to the database, print 'login successful' and log out. Calling print(fms) returns

```py
<Server logged_in=False database=Hangtag Order Management layout=OrderAdmin>
```

but i receive the connection error upon the login attempt. I am assuming the error is server side, but i dont know enough about servers to accurately trouble shoot. Could the server have blacklisted my IP for making so many login attempts during my testing? and if so where would i undo that/prevent it from happening again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of server reboots fixed the error, not really sure of the ultimate cause.